# Is there a difference between a tempco resistor and a thermistor?

Tags: resistors, thermal, thermistor

That is, other than just the nomenclature.

Comment: both "can" mean to be used for compensation.

Comment: VISHAY Corp has 5ppm/degree C resistors People love those Tempcos.

Answer (score 1):

Thermistors have a much higher variation of resistance, a thermistor can change from the 100Ω's to kΩ's (and 100kΩ's) over a range of 100C°.

A tempco resistor usually has its resistance change by 100ppm's or 1000ppm's which would be less than an ohm over a 100C° range

Comment: You can use HTML `&deg;` for the degrees symbol. Also `&Omega;` and `&mu;` are handy. The are not rendered in the comments.

Comment: Why would you ever use a tempco then and not an RTD? I didn't even know tempcos existed until this question.

Comment: Temp comp of log amps is one application that comes to mind.

Comment: If you need only a small linear change, then use a tempco. If you need to keep a parameter of the circuit within tolerance then a tempco can help with that.

Comment: Also if you want a degree symbol that does render in comments, backslash, string, hat, backslash, "circ", backslash, string.  Gives you \$^\circ\$.  Hope that makes sense.  Not sure how to write mathjaxx commands without them appearing rendered.

Comment: @KH Having compose functionality is very useful and I highly recommend looking up wincompose if you're on windows. Simple mnemonic key sequences to insert most any character you want, and the ability to add custom ones for the places the built-in ones are lacking.

Comment: @Hearth Oooooo I like!  Thanks I'll try it out.

Comment: Hmm my method only renders in comments on my desktop, not my mobile.